# Two tables one view ASP MVC

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2

I need some help. What I am trying to do is show the locations of a device belonging to a specific project.

On the projects page I have a button which goes to the google map. For projects I have a Projects model and controller.
I've got 2 tables, a table containing the location of a device and a project table. I want to display all device locations belonging to a project on a google map. The google maps part is working and I managed to show all device locations on 1 map, only problem is I can't seem to link the devices to the project. I need some help on how to achieve this.

In the Location table ive got a foreign key to the projects table. this is a many-to-onerelation. A project can have multiple devices, but a device can only be linked to 1 project. I have defined the relation as follows in the location model:

```
[BelongsTo("ProjectID")]
        public Project project
        {
            get { return _project; }
            set { _project = value; }
        }
```

In the Location controller I use the following code(theres more but for the moment its not relevant):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(DeviceLocation.FindAll());
     }
```

This simply lists all locations in the location table. What I need is to list all locations where the ProjectID = the ID of the projects table. I'm coming from PHP/MYSQL and there you would simply join the 2 tables. How do I achieve this with asp mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on LINQ and how to use it to query your data.

Something like this should help:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(DeviceLocation.Where(d=> d.ProjectId == myProjectId));
     }
```